# How can I add multiple columns from multiple rows in 1 table along with 1 row from another?

Tags: php, mysql

We are keeping our invoices in one table called invoices_v3 and payments in a table called payments_v3. It is entirely possible that each invoice has multiple payments.

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(invoices_v3.invoice_amount - payments_v3.pago_in_cash + payments_v3.pago_in_ccrd + payments_v3.pago_in_bnkd + payments_v3.pago_in_coup + payments_v3.pago_in_chek) AS end_balance 
FROM invoices_v3, payments_v3
WHERE payments_v3.invoice_no=invoices_v3.invoice_id AND invoices_v3.client_id = '$clean_id'
ORDER BY invoices_v3.invoice_id DESC
```

I am trying to have it return all results from invoices_v3 where `invoices_v3.client_id = '$clean_id'` and in the same result have end_balance have the sum of all the payments where `payments_v3.invoice_no=invoices_v3.invoice_id`. What it is doing right now is returning only 1 result (the last invoice only) with end_balance having the sum off ALL payments that match $clean_id (client id).

I am trying to do this without JOINS if possible because this script will be accessed really often and some client ids might have hundreds of invoices each with multiple payments.

**EDIT:**

Here is the JOIN I tried:

```
SELECT invoices_v3.*,
SUM(payments_v3.pago_in_cash + payments_v3.pago_in_ccrd + payments_v3.pago_in_bnkd + payments_v3.pago_in_coup + payments_v3.pago_in_chek) AS total_payments
FROM invoices_v3
LEFT JOIN payments_v3 ON invoices_v3.invoice_id=payments_v3.invoice_no
WHERE invoices_v3.client_id = '$clean_id'
AND payments_v3.old_invoice_no=invoices_v3.invoice_id <-- DELETE THIS LINE
GROUP BY invoices_v3.invoice_id
ORDER BY invoices_v3.invoice_id DESC
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | invoices_v3 | ref  | inv_v1_cliente | inv_v1_cliente | 5       | const |     31 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | payments_v3 | ALL  | NULL           | NULL           | NULL    | NULL  | 147706 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `GROUP BY` clause to your SQL

Add a `COALESCE` statement around your `SUM` to account for no payments existing for an invoice

```
SELECT *, 
COALESCE(SUM(invoices_v3.invoice_amount - payments_v3.pago_in_cash + payments_v3.pago_in_ccrd + payments_v3.pago_in_bnkd + payments_v3.pago_in_coup + payments_v3.pago_in_chek),invoices_v3.invoice_amount) AS end_balance 
FROM invoices_v3, payments_v3
WHERE payments_v3.invoice_no=invoices_v3.invoice_id AND invoices_v3.client_id = '$clean_id'
GROUP BY invoices_v3.invoice_id
ORDER BY invoices_v3.invoice_id DESC
```

If there are no payments for an invoice, the invoice amount will display.